# show in one column by selecting from multiple column by date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

Database Table `Request`.......

```
user_name   sim_type    mobile_no   sim_id  request_amount   request_date
Rahim       Prepaid     01913644900     3   98      01/08/2014 13:45
Rahim       Prepaid     01790117748     1   50      01/08/2014 13:55
Rahim       Prepaid     01836650415     2   100         01/09/2014 15:29
Rahim       Prepaid     01553698741     3   100         01/09/2014 15:29
Rahim       Prepaid     01736005131     1   100         01/09/2014 15:30
```

My Output will be........

```
user_name    sim_id1    sim_id2    sim_id3    total_amount    request_date
Rahim           50         0          98          148          01/08/2014
Rahim           100        100        100         300          01/09/2014
```

Comment: what did you try so far...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_name, DATE(request_date) request_date, 
       SUM(IF(sim_id = 1, request_amount, 0)) sim_id1, 
       SUM(IF(sim_id = 2, request_amount, 0)) sim_id2, 
       SUM(IF(sim_id = 3, request_amount, 0)) sim_id3, 
       SUM(request_amount) total_amount
FROM Request 
GROUP BY user_name, DATE(request_date)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is working well. But i m still there i can't get data per date. Can you help me...

Comment: I am unable to fetch the data per every request_datetime. Can you help me pls?

Comment: @user3177042 Do you want to fetch the date for both date ans time wise?

Comment: Exactly, To the output of previous post. Your sql fetch the total data of two date range but not separately. I want to fetch data separately for every date.

Comment: @user3177042 Then don not use `DATE` function in `GROUP BY` clause. Replace `GROUP BY user_name, DATE(request_date)` with `GROUP BY user_name, request_date`

Comment: @user3177042 You're most welcome. As an active member of Stackoverflow  you have to accept the answer by clicking on TRUE sign at the left side of question on the answer which will fulfill your requirement. Check the http://stackoverflow.com/tour